# Google App Engine + SOAPConnection error

Tags: java, google-app-engine, soap

Problem in SOAP connection 
I'm trying build SOAP connection.

```
SOAPConnection con = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance() .createConnection();
SOAPMessage resMsg = con.call(reqMsg, "https://www.eway.com.au/gateway/rebill/test/managerebill_test.asmx");
con.close();
```

I called this method on main() method it still ok. 
But when I tried to call on dev environment or server google appengine it will error.

```
    SEVERE: SAAJ0540: Error during saving a multipart message
com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Error during saving a multipart message
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.eway.soap.server.SoapRequestServlet.createCustomer(SoapRequestServlet.java:187)

Caused by: javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactoryConfigurationError: Provider org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl not found
    at javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory.newInstance(Unknown Source)
```

Anyone has faced this issue before. Can you help me?

Comment: Do you use any of these xerces, xalan, and xml-api dependencies. if so just remove those and try it

Comment: No, I don't use these libraries. Just google app engine SDK 1.7.2 and JRE6

Comment: I didn't import those library, but as your comment, I downloaded and imported them. Build again and it run miracle :). Thanks you so much.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely due to the fact that it is not able to find the correct TransformerFactory implementation from your linked libraries and CLASSPATH. Check if this helps you: http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/issues/detail?id=9